# scala spark -count even numbers from file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am New to Big Data World.need yours help to make it real.here is my question
I am Reading data from txt file(1,2,3,4,4,4,4)

```
var file=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/MyData/Lab1/numbers.txt")
var number=file.flatMap(line=>line.split(","))
var intNumbers=number.map(num=>num.toInt)//Error
intNumbers.collect()
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

error is coming due to last element of array not able to convert to Int

Please help on that
Thanks In Advance.

Regards,
Learning Spark

Comment: Maybe an empty line in your txt file? Check your txt-file again.

Comment: thanks for your answer but nothing is there here is my data 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have filter empty string before casting to Integer.

```
var file=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/MyData/Lab1/numbers.txt")
var number=file.flatMap(line=>line.split(",")).filter(num => num != "")
var intNumbers=number.map(num=>num.toInt)//Error
intNumbers.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks you Kaushal,1st question of life in StackOverflow u solved it:) thank you very much.